# Azure IoT Hub Python SDK on ESP32

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Despite not tested or supported as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-sdk-platform-support), can Azure IoT Python SDK be deployed on ESP32? Or I need to use MQTT Protocol directly to connect with Azure IoT Hub?